# Cucumber Step definition creation for tests from a feature file in Intellij is camel case

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, junit4, camelcasing, snakecase

In my Project I do not use "Cucumber Java" rather use "**Junit** 4" in my "**Run configurations**".
I have searched and found that the **"Program arguments"** in the other case, i.e, "Cucumber java" can be changed to "--snippet underscore" however in Junit the underscore for the **Cucumber options** is the default so I do not need to change it nor add a property file containing this configuration.
I also tried to add it in my **Pom**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NFAN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CvCq.png)

The problem is that the auto generated code for creating the definition step is in camel case.
I use Gherkin and cucumber for Java as plugins in my IDE "**IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)**".
The Operating system is Linux Ubuntu.

Is there a way to get the **snake-case "also called as underscore case"** instead of the camel case directly without the need to install additional plugins such as "CamelCase" or "String Manipulation" to in a 2nd step change the generated Camel case into snake case?

Thanks in advance for your support.

See above the whole background and trials and expectations